# How to link one JS file to two HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML files, both are linked to one JS file. The first HTML file can be manipulated by the js but the other way around for the second one. Does this mean I need separate JS files for the two?

Comment: It actually depends on how you are using your js file. If you include both `.js` file into your `HTML` files using `<script></script>` tag then both will work fine with one `js` file.

Comment: No separate file is required as long as the DOM structure is the same in both the HTML files so that your DOM manipulation code can find the right element(s) to work upon

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't work for the second one. I created another file, now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean?

> HTML Homepage.html using App.js
>
> HTML Detailpage.html depend on App.js
>
> JS App.js responsible for manipulating Homepage.html and also Detailpage.html

You can reuse `js` multiple times on different `html` files. However, I'd strongly recommend you to think of encapsulation and easy to understand logic & flow.
If that means you need to create different `js` then do it, especially when you are working with multiple developers. Long and complex `js` will easily cause unintended bugs in the future.

Comment: So .... It is better to use multilple files?  Okay, thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend so, yes. Basically it's better to have multiple understandable and readable js files than one giant complex js file. Your fellow developers will love you and appreciate that in the long run :)